# I want to automount USB with Nautilus in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, nautilus, automount, thunar

I have installed Nautilus in my **Xubuntu** 16.04. and selected it as preferred file manager in *Preferred Applications*.
Now the problem is that Thunar still operates in Xubuntu, for example, when I insert a USB, it is *Thunar* that opens it and not *Nautilus*.

How can I make *Nautilus* file manager the standard application to automount media in **Xubuntu** 16.04. instead of *Thunar*?

Thanks!

**Update:**
I removed `Thunar` and now, when I plug a USB-external it is not automatically mounted though in `dconfig-editor` the `media-handling` is in `automount=true` and `automount-open=true`.

Comment: Please show `xdg-mime query default inode/directory`

Comment: @nobody the output is `exo-file-manager.desktop`. I hope it helps to find the solution. Surely, I am not the only one trying to make nautilus a full operative file manager in xfce desktop. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have been all over the internet, I want to achieve the same. This is what I found that is relatively simple, and tested in my Xfce4:

[udiskie](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie)

```
sudo apt install -y udiskie
```

Should be enough for the installation.

It uses the default file browser, but you can configure that:

```
udiskie -f nautilus
```

**Drawback:** I can't find any option to open the browser automatically. It shows a pop-up where it gives you the option to open the file with the browser.

[man page](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coldfix/udiskie/master/doc/udiskie.8.txt)

Comment: Thanks @guillermo A comfort, that more people are looking for a solution to the same problem. I am waiting for the ideal solution without extra package :-\ I am sure there is only some setting that must be adjusted. ;)

Comment: If you find it, would you let me know here if that's not too much trouble :)?

Comment: Of course. I am waiting for @nobody to answer my message, but nobody answers. ;-)

Comment: I'll try many things, but it seems that xfce4 uses hard-bitten thunar-volman for automounting.  :(